# Adding array of images to the stage with easeljs and preloadjs

Tags: easeljs, preloadjs

Different images should appear on stage. For this I am trying to create an array and put it in a container but id doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
var imagesPic = queue.loadManifest(["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"]);

var w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

container = new createjs.Container();
stage.addChild(container);

captureContainers = [];
captureIndex = 0;

for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        container.addChild(imagesPic);  
}

for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
        var captureContainer = new createjs.Container();
        captureContainer.cache(0,0,w,h);
        captureContainers.push(captureContainer);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Your imagesPic will be null (loadManifest doesn't return anything), and you are caching a bunch of empty containers.

Comment: Thank for answering! I make a game. And now I'm trying to make something like rain of different images.

Comment: There is no reason to cache images, unless you plan on filtering them, or somehow changing them in memory (like combining multiple images into one for performance reasons). Currently your example does nothing, except preload the images. There is no handler though to do anything with those images.